# Get the next pair of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with values i would like to extract. Here is the stature of the list.

```
 input =  [
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2019-05-07 13: 40: 31.103"
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "value": 22
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "123 aaa 456 bbb"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2019-05-08 13: 40: 31.103"
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "value": 11
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "123 yyy 456 zzz"
    }
  ]
  ,
  ...
]
```

I would like to iterate the list and get the values of `@timestamp` and `@message` for each iteration. The timestamp is always the first element of each list and the message is the third one, But i don't want to rely on element's order.

Here is want i've done so far, But i don't know how to get the next pair.

```
for list in input:
    for dict in list:
        for x, y in dict.items():
            if x == 'field' and y == '@timestamp':
                print(y)
                # Here i want to get the values of the next pair and continue to the next iteration
            elif x == 'field' and y == '@message':
                print(y)
                # Here i want to get the values of the next pair and continue to the next iteration
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: this is a bad idea with regular dictionaries, the keys are not ordered there is no correct "next" if you insist on doing this, turn your dict into [ordered dicts](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the next pair", can you please elaborate?

Comment: You should avoid naming variables the same as built-ins

Comment: @Faboor, The next pair of `"field": "@timestamp"` for example would be  `"value": "2019-05-07 13: 40: 31.103"`. I hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple iteration

**Ex:**

```
data =  [
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2019-05-07 13: 40: 31.103"
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "value": 22
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "123 aaa 456 bbb"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "field": "@timestamp",
      "value": "2019-05-08 13: 40: 31.103"
    },
    {
      "field": "B",
      "value": 11
    },
    {
      "field": "@message",
      "value": "123 yyy 456 zzz"
    }
  ]
]

for elem in data:
    for sub_elem in elem:
        if sub_elem["field"] in ["@timestamp", "@message"]:
            print(sub_elem["value"])
```

**Output:**

```
2019-05-07 13: 40: 31.103
123 aaa 456 bbb
2019-05-08 13: 40: 31.103
123 yyy 456 zzz
```

Comment: Great! Much more easy than i thought. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an enumerator to the list counting the current index in the loop. Then extract the dictionary at that value.

```
for list in input:
    for i, dict in enumerate(list):
        for x, y in dict.items():
            if x == 'field' and (y == '@timestamp' or y == '@message'):
                print(list[i])
```

prints:

```
{'field': '@timestamp', 'value': '2019-05-07 13: 40: 31.103'}
{'field': '@message', 'value': '123 aaa 456 bbb'}
{'field': '@timestamp', 'value': '2019-05-08 13: 40: 31.103'}
{'field': '@message', 'value': '123 yyy 456 zzz'}
```